# VSCode IntelliSense for commonJS modules using path.join()

Tags: node.js, adobe, require, commonjs, complex-event-processing

In an Adobe CEP panel that I am working on which also uses NodeJS, I have been using the following approach to require other modules:

```js
require('path');
const moduleA = require(path.join(__dirname, "/*PATH-TO*/module_A.js"));
const moduleB = require(path.join(__dirname, "/*PATH-TO*/module_B.js"));
```

My problem is that VSCode doesn't parse those files and I am not getting IntelliSense autocomplete after requiring those modules.

**Is there a way to make IntelliSense work with such code?**

--
Note:
That's the only way I could get After-Effects to find those modules, using relative paths gives me errors: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './module_A'`. I have also tried using paths relative to the project folder.

(Alternatively, I would love to know how to make `require()` work with relative paths in an After-Effects CEP panel, but in this case my project is already full of these requires statements)

Comment: Use `const moduleA = require("./path/to/module_A.js");`. Note that the path should be relative to the current file, not to the project root.

Comment: This works inside already required modules, but not inside the entry file. I guess it's because it's not quite a nodeJS app that has an entry point